# How to use GestureDetector on Stack's children elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm designing a profile image widget and I need to perform 2 different tasks.

[image]

Edit icon will change the profile image and Clicking on the image will enlarge the image but I got these errors instead :

```
    I/flutter (21524): The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector(state:
    I/flutter (21524): RawGestureDetectorState#6b90e(gestures: [tap])):
    I/flutter (21524): Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
    I/flutter (21524): Positioned widgets must be placed directly inside Stack widgets.
    I/flutter (21524): Positioned(no depth, top: 0.0, right: 2.0, dirty) has a Stack ancestor, but there are other widgets
    I/flutter (21524): between them:
    I/flutter (21524): - Listener(listeners: [down], behavior: deferToChild)
    I/flutter (21524): - _GestureSemantics
    I/flutter (21524): These widgets cannot come between a Positioned and its Stack.
    I/flutter (21524): The ownership chain for the parent of the offending Positioned was:
    I/flutter (21524):   Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← Stack ← Padding ← Column ←
    I/flutter (21524):   Center ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← ⋯
```

Here's my code :

```
      Stack(children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap : openImage
                  child: Container(
                    width: 120.0,
                    height: 120.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: new NetworkImage(user.dp ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                        new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(100.0)),
                        border: new Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 2.0,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: uploadImage,
                  child: Positioned(
                    child: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                    right: 2.0, top: 0.0,),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: you have `GestureDetector` between `Stack` and `Positioned` - the error says: *"Positioned widgets must be placed directly inside Stack widgets. [...] These widgets cannot come between a Positioned and its Stack."*

Comment: Wrap circle avatar with gesture detector .. not positioned widget. Remove that.

Comment: Have you found the solution in your problem? If not, could you please provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we could understand well how your code works? I'm trying to replicate the code you've given but it seems that it has some missing essential parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key detail on the logs displayed:

`"Positioned widgets must be placed directly inside Stack widgets."`

The reason of this issue is that `Positioned` widget is wrapped inside `GestureDetector`. To solve this error, add `Positioned` in the `Stack`, then wrap `GestureDetector` with it.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        debugPrint('Clicked open image');
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 120.0,
        height: 120.0,
        ...
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          debugPrint('Clicked edit image');
        },
        child: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.edit)),
      ),
      right: 2.0,
      top: 0.0,
    ),
  ],
),
```